# How to render component over Lottie

Tags: react-native, animation, lottie

Is there any way to render components over LottieView like button on top and Lottie animation on background in React Native

```
   <LottieView
    style={{ width: 400, height: 600 }}
    source={require('../components/user.json')}
    autoPlay
    loop
  >
    <Button
      onPress={onPressLearnMore}
      title='Learn More'
      color='#841584'
      accessibilityLabel='Learn more about this purple button'
    />
  </LottieView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use button and text on top and lottieview animation on background by this way:

```
   return(
        <View style = {{width:'100%', height:'100%', backgroundColor:'white'}}>
            <LottieView source={require('../Animations/74468-rocket.json')} autoPlay loop></LottieView>
            <Text style= {{fontSize:32, fontWeight:'bold', marginTop:400}}>hello i am on top</Text>
            <Button
                title='Learn More'
                color='#841584'
                accessibilityLabel='Learn more about this purple button'
            />
        </View> 
    )
```

i hope it will help you.. [image]